# Java Concatenating Ever Growing String java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, runtime-error

*I get an error from automated JUnit 4 unit testing software that my course instructor uses to automatically check assignments. We upload our draft code to a cloud program tester which automatically checks and grades the assignments.*

**Note: I am allowed to ask questions on StackOverflow per instructor.**

This is week ~3 of first semester. I've never coded in Java before. We have only discussed up to functions (including  if/else, while, loops, switch) so I can't use features from future modules.

We were not given a class tutorial on this specific assignment. The unit was on flow control.

My code (below) runs okay in the VSCODE IDE cloud the school provided.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SplitString {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String output = "";

    do {
  
      String inputString = scanner.nextLine();

      if (!inputString.equals(" ")) {
        output += inputString;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    } while (true);
    System.out.println(output);
    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

I get this back

```
java.lang.RuntimeException 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your application is expecting user input when no user input suppose to be given. Please take a look at the 'Caused by...' section of this stack trace for details of where the problem occurred in your code.
I get this feedback (which I don't understand)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your application is expecting user input when no user input suppose to be given. Please take a look at the 'Caused by...' section of this stack trace for details of where the problem occurred in your code.
at tests.HomeworkTests.lambda$test_splitString$5(HomeworkTests.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at defaultPackage.SplitString.main(SplitString.java:13)
at tests.HomeworkTests.lambda$test_splitString$5(HomeworkTests.java:245)
```

The program **test** enters strings such as hello hello hello and supposed to stop at a blank line. Per the assignment *"When this application receives a blank input, this application should stop receiving input and print the growing string to the console. The last string that this program should print is the result of the growing string."*

At first I tried another method that just stopped at ENTER but then I got a different error (other code below.) That showed me the test was ending with a " " blank space not ENTER. Although the instructor said in discussion it presses enter. So I'm basically lost.

Here is the old code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SplitString {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);
    String stringInput;
    String output = "";

    do {
      stringInput = sx.nextLine();
     
      output += stringInput;
      
    } while (!stringInput.isEmpty());

    System.out.println(output);
    sx.close();
  }
}
```

Gives this error

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 12, length 3
at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
at homework.SplitString.main(SplitString.java:65)
at tests.HomeworkTests.lambda$test_splitString$5(HomeworkTests.java:288)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Any help would be appreciated to:

- Explain where I'm going wrong or what I need to fix or something I could try
- Explain what the errors mean that I'm getting (or where I can learn more about understanding the errors and how to read what to fix from them

Thank you for your time and support and patience <3.

I expected for the program to concatenate the user provided string until a blank is entered then print the resulting string to the console.

Comment: *first* part (`NoSuchElementException`): `" "` is not a blank line (or blank string) - it contains a whitespace character, probably this is never being input by user || *second* part (`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`): the posted stack trace seems to come from calling `substring()` (line 65 of SplitString.java,) but but that method is not being called in posted code - it is not the code where this Exception is being thrown

Comment: Strange. For clarity, are you saying that the second code is having an error for a function that doesn't exist in the code - or that perhaps the test is looking  for a function that doesn't exist? Sorry, I'm so new to this. And thank you for your clarity on the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems blank line means empty line.
Because it is not clear from requirements what the terminator should be, use trim() to remove all whitespaces, and if after trim the line is empty, then stop.
Here is the corrected code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SplitString{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        String output = "";
        try (  Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ); ){
            do{
                String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
                if( inputString.trim().isEmpty() ){
                    break;
                }
                output += inputString;
            } while( true );
        }
        System.out.println( output );
    }
}
```

Comment: That sends me: "defaultPackage/SplitString.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
try ( Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ); ){" But I will try trim in the other code. Thank you for explaining about the blank line.

Comment: BTW no need to have the first `try` - code did not open `System.in`, better not close it (as posted, it will be closed when the `Scanner` is closed, Same true for code posted in question)

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight. Sadly, I'm so new that I'm not familiar with the lingo enough to really understand what you're saying (or most others for that matter.) It's the hardest barrier for me in all of this to become familiar to even understand instructions, errors, or solutions. Any clarity would really help.

Is what you mean that I can omit the try code "around" the solution? If yes, I did try that. The system is timing out so I can't get any feedback from it as of yet. But I will post as soon as its working. As for closing the scanner, do you mean I don't have to close it?

Comment: `try ( Scanner scanner = ... ) { ... }` is creating a statement that will close the `scanner` instance after the block terminates execution - when closed the `Scanner`, on the other side, will also close the argument used top create it (`System.in` - the standard input- in this case). Usually only code that opened a resource (like `System.in`) should close it (unless otherwise documented, in special cases). Standard input is even worse, it cannot be re-opened if eventually needed somewhere else in the program.